# Want to create a proper response from laravel collection?

Tags: collections, logic, laravel-6

Assume this in a collection 
want in a date from 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-04

```
[[
{"id" : "1", "name" : "A", "type": "t1" ,"date" : "2021-01-01"},
{"id" : "2", "name" : "B", "type": "t2" "date" : "2021-01-01"},
{"id" : "3", "name" : "C", "type": "t1" "date" : "2021-01-02"},
{"id" : "4", "name" : "D", "type": "t3" "date" : "2021-01-02"},
{"id" : "5", "name" : "E", "type": "t2" "date" : "2021-01-01"},
]]
```

I want a out put like this

```
[{
     0: {date: "2021-01-01", record:[0: {"id": 1, "name": "A"}]}, 
     1: {date: "2021-01-02", record:[0: {"id": 3, "name": "C"}},
     2: {date: "2021-01-03"},
     3: {date: "2021-01-04"},
     "type": "t1"
   },{
     0: {date: "2021-01-01", record:[0: {"id": 2, "name": "B"}, 1: {"id": 5, "name": "E"}]}, 
     1: {date: "2021-01-02"},
     2: {date: "2021-01-03"},
     3: {date: "2021-01-04"},
     "type": "t2"
   },{
     0: {date: "2021-01-01"}, 
     1: {date: "2021-01-02", record:[0: {"id": 4, "name": "D"}]},
     2: {date: "2021-01-03"},
     3: {date: "2021-01-04"},
     "type": "t3"
   }]
```

Any help will be really appreciated